# How many Azure B2C can be created in one directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I already have an Azure B2C in one directory so my question Can I create another B2C in same directory or do I need to create a new directory for another B2C.

Comment: When you tried to create another B2C in the same directory, what happened?

Comment: @Sai vallap, you can create max 20 B2C tenants from your base directory (Default Directory) or from the Directory where you have valid subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

You can create multiple Azure AD B2C tenants based on the same Azure AD.

That means you have an Azure AD tenant A. And you create an Azure AD B2C tenant B based on the Azure subscription of Azure AD tenant A.

Here tenant B is not in tenant A. So "I already have an Azure B2C in one directory" is incorrect. The B2C tenant B is a directory itself. It's not in one directory.

After that you can also create an Azure AD B2C tenant C based on the Azure subscription of Azure AD tenant A.

I guess you are asking if you could create a new B2C tenant C in tenant B. The answer is **NO**.

If you have Azure subscription in tenant B, you could create a new B2C tenant C based on the Azure subscription of tenant B. But it's a complete new B2C tenant. It is not in tenant B.